# Python 3.x. Использование global на аргументе функции

Tags: python-3.x, область-видимости, передача-параметров

Пусть, есть у нас функция, которая принимает на вход переменную, ссылающуюся на список, и меняет ее, заставляя ссылаться на словарь:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
def f(x):
    global a
    a = {'spam' : 1}
```

Теперь у нас глобальная переменная ссылается на словарь.

Все отлично работает, но что, если мы хотим написать функцию в более общем виде, чтобы она работала с любой глобальной переменной, которая может иметь произвольное имя?

```
 a = [1, 2, 3]
def f(x):
    global x
    a = {'spam' : 1}
```

Тут либо выходит ошибка (так как х уже является глобальной переменной), либо, если убрать global, то просто будет создана локальная переменная.

В итоге, задача следующая:
Функция должна принимать глобальную переменную в качестве аргумента и переопределять ее (именно ее, а не ее компонент), при этом имя этой глобальной переменной функция не знает, знает только имя аргумента. Функция не должна ничего возвращать (никаких return или yield). Есть ли способ создать такую функцию (если да - то можно пример)?

Comment: Решение - не использовать глобальные переменные, использовать возвращаемое значение функции и снаружи присваивать его в нужную переменную.

Comment: @insolor - я специально написал, что функция не должна ничего возвращать, т.е. конструкции типа a = f(a) не вариант. Как пример - функцию будут вызывать, просто передав ей аргумент, другие люди и изменить их код вызова я не могу.

Comment: Ответ - так как вы хотите сделать не получится. Нельзя передать переменную как аргумент. Используйте глобальный словарь, например, в функции принимайте имя ключа, по этому ключу в словарь записывайте значение.

Comment: "изменить их код вызова я не могу" - а как вы из этого кода вызова собрались (гипотетически) передавать глобальную переменную, если код вызова нельзя менять?

Comment: Если вы найдёте способ сделать что-то подобное — для вас начнут готовить котёл в аду

Comment: Для решения этой задачи придуманы замыкания. Глобальные переменные не нужны.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наверное, вот так, хотя не совсем уверен, что вы хотели:

```py
a = [1, 2, 3]
def f(x):
    globals()[x] = {'spam' : 1}

f('a')
print(a)
# {'spam': 1}
```